# Autoload classes with namespaces defined by lookup path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, domain-driven-design, autoload, bounded-contexts

I am trying to build a Rails 5.2.x application that closely resembles the structure of bounded contexts according to Domain-driven Design.

Given that `identity` is the name of a bounded context which contains the entities `user` and `group`, I would like to have a directory structure like this:

```
<RAILS ROOT>/identity/user.rb
<RAILS ROOT>/identity/group.rb
```

I would like these to contain the classes `Identity::User` and `Identity::Group` respectively.

Inspired by the `bounded_context` gem, I added the following line to my `application.rb`:

```
config.paths.add 'identity', eager_load: true
```

Sadly, this doesn't really match what I had in mind. Using this approach, Rails seems to require me to setup the directory structure like this:

```
<RAILS ROOT>/identity/identity/user.rb
<RAILS ROOT>/identity/identity/group.rb
```

Which is not exactly what I had in mind.

Is there a way to make Rails' autoloader understand, that all the files in my path already are within the namespace `Identity`, so I don't have to reflect this in the directory structure again?

Comment: If you drop the config setting, and stick the `identify` folder inside of rails root `app`, it will auto load them and allow you to wrap the Identity module/namespace around them

Comment: Which is what I intended to avoid. I would like separate my bounded contexts clearly and have them visible on the root directory level. And the relevant files right in these directories.